# Can I set-up theme for 'view-source' in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, view-source

I installed theme for Developers Tools and want also make my 'view-source' is dark too.

Comment: may be this will help you.[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci?hl=en]

Comment: Thank you but this extension not working when I press Ctrl + U

Answer (score 28):

Create bookmark with code below:

```
javascript:(function(){ var h=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],s=document.createElement('style');s.setAttribute('type','text/css'); s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('html{-webkit-filter:invert(100%) hue-rotate(180deg) contrast(70%) !important; background: #fff;} .line-content {background-color: #fefefe;}'));h.appendChild(s); })()
```

And click on this bookmark on any page you want to be dark

Comment: This is the _only_ thing that worked! Even the _userstyles.org_ was deceitful/misleading. It said "install this with Stylish!" then didn't even install it with the only button that was there. Then, when you go back, it says: "This can't be used on Chrome!" Are you serious? A web-developer-type site that can't even check what browser you're using?

Comment: @Gauthier your code will not work on every page, my code will work on every website across the internet, not only view-source page

Comment: Lol, you are correct. I was only after view-source . Yours is way better in that respected

Comment: Total epic fail on my part. I prolly would have found that in the next few weeks. I was using it to print_r($var) in php. Im just going to delete out my comment, until i work though my epic fail. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Very useful, thanks! Now I just wish javascript injection from tampermonkey would work with this.

Comment: Thank god now I don't have to post my almost identical solution :) Great job! 

Answer (score 4):

The only real way to do this is I found is the `#enable-force-dark` experimental flag. The downside is that it sets a dark theme on every single page you browser like [Dark Reader](https://darkreader.org/) or [Deluminate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/deluminate/iebboopaeangfpceklajfohhbpkkfiaa).

1. Enable the `#enable-force-dark` experimental flag at `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQGGZ.png)
2. Done. Now the `view-source` pages are automatically dark.

Comment: This should be the answer, as it's in the default build.

Answer (score 0):

There're some syntax highlighter extensions available for chrome. Such as:  [Sight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sight/epmaefhielclhlnmjofcdapbeepkmggh) and [Syntaxtic!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/syntaxtic/cgjalgdhmbpaacnnejmodfinclbdgaci).

But to be honest the result isn't always as expected because those apps relying on the url having an extension (.js, .php and so on) to load the proper highlighter. This days most websites are using url rewriting so there is not extension at all so the apps doesen't load the highlighter. Maybe this could be tweaked in the app manifests but I haven't touched this yet.

Comment: Yes, I also use this nice theme, but I need to see dark background of `view-source:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546055/can-i-set-up-theme-for-view-source-in-chrome/35996658`

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich Sorry my mistake. I just modified my answer to adapt it to your true needs.